# Analyzing data with unequal sample sizes

Tags: r, excel, analysis

I am analyzing 11 data sets where no 2 datasets have equal rows (some have 1800, others have 1300, etc...)

If the datasets have the weights of a specific packages, i'm taking the sum of the weights and seeing ranking the data sets in order by the sum of their weight. But, i would like to take into consideration that some data sets have more rows.

What are some ways i can produce a good answer but keep in consideration that the sizes of the data set are different.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: All depends upon what weight you want to allocate to the number. A simple way would be [Weight] + [Number] which would rank the set with a larger number higher if the weight is nearly the same but number is clearly secondary. [Weight] * [Number] (or derivatives thereof) would give weight and number equal weight. Then you can go into [Weight] + x[Number] or x[Weight] * y[Number] - whichever way drives you nuts first :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use average weight rather than total weight if that is what you are actually interested in (which it seems like if you are concerned with the different numbers of items).